# Swift 4: Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization when converting Objective-c to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, typedef, type-alias

I'm trying to convert an Objective-C project to Swift, here is one of the .h file in Objective-C:

```
typedef void(^PrintBlock)(HLPrinter *printer);

@interface ShoppingViewController : UIViewController

@property (copy, nonatomic) PrintBlock printBlock;

@end
```

and in the .m file, there is a function:

```
HLPrinter *printer = [self getPrinter];

if (_printBlock) {
    _printBlock(printer);
}
```

And this is how I converted it into Swift:

```
typealias PrintBlock = (_ printer: HLPrinter?) -> Void
```

But when I tried to convert the function above into Swift, I get a `'Non-nominal type 'PrintBlock' (aka '(Optional<HLPrinter>) -> ()') does not support explicit initialization'` error when I was trying to declare a variable with type `PrintBlock`:

```
let pb = PrintBlock()
```

I'm not familiar with Objective-C, so how should I convert that function with `_printerBlock` into Swift?

Comment: You are initialising  PrintBlock  with PrintBlock() that is not allowed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintBlock` is an alias for a closure. You can't simply create an instance like you would a class or struct. You need to assign a closure (or function) to the property.

The Swift code would be:

```
typealias PrintBlock = (_ printer: HLPrinter?) -> Void

class ShoppingViewController: UIViewController {
    var printBlock: PrintBlock?

    func getPrinter() -> HLPrinter {
        return somePrinter
    }

    func someFunction() {
        if let printBlock = printBlock {
            let printer = getPrinter()
            printBlock(printer)
        }
    }
}
```

The calling code would be something like:

```
let vc = ShoppingViewController()
vc.printBlock = { (printer) in
    // do something with printer
}
```

Or if you have a function:

```
func someFunction(_ printer: HLPrinter) {
}
```

You can assign that:

```
vc.printBlock = someFunction
```

There's a few assumptions in here based on the partial information you have provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialise the Closure , For you requirement you can simply create variable just like property in objc

```
typealias Listener = (HLPrinter) -> ()

var lister:Listener?
```

And  on some event

```
 self.lister?(value)
```

Hope it is helpful