# Non-nominal type does not support explicit initialization

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

This question has been asked a few times, beneath my question are the linked other questions with an explanation why it didn't worked out well.

This is my code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    init()
}

protocol Initializable where Self: SomeProtocol {}

protocol ProtocolA {
    associatedtype A: Initializable
}

extension ProtocolA {
    func a() {
        A()
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Non-nominal type 'Self.A' does not support explicit initialization
```

I do not understand why not. The associated type `A` always is a type of `SomeProtocol`, which has the initializer.

Tried:
[non-nominal type X does not support explicit initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458657/non-nominal-type-x-does-not-support-explicit-initialization) : Type 'Self.A' has no member 'init'
[Swift 4: Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization when converting Objective-c to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577264/swift-4-non-nominal-type-t-does-not-support-explicit-initialization-when-conv) : whole something else
[Swift 4: "Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348627/swift-4-non-nominal-type-t-does-not-support-explicit-initialization) : I think the compiler doesn't really have the know the exact type.

Comment: In this case in the `where` clause `Self` must be constrained to a concrete type, not a protocol. A protocol is not a generic. In some of the linked questions generics are used which are also concrete types at the moment the method is called.

Comment: In Swift 4.2, superclass constrained protocols aren't properly implemented yet – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913244/2976878 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647762/2976878. In the latest master snapshot, your code works as expected.

Comment: But until then, you can just use the short-form equivalent: `protocol Initializable : SomeProtocol {}`

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for (again) notifying me about improvements in later releases of Swift :)